# Access nid in field template

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, entities

How do I access the `nid` of the current `node` in a `field.html.twig` template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself a solution for this. Maybe not the perfect way to go, but it worked very well for my needs:

in .theme-file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
   $variables['nodenid'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node');
}
```

and in .twig:

```
{{ nodenid }}
```

of course you might want to filter the preprocess hook to only add this variable to a specific field.